# Delete many items with foreach and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Please see the details :

**Database records**

JN_Country Records :

[image]

JN_Players Records :

[image]

this is my code :

```
List<int> ids=new List<int> {12, 14};
            foreach (var item in ids)
            {
                try
                {
                    _service.Delete(item);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
```

First time => item is 12

error :

> InnerException    {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
>   constraint \"FK_dbo.JN_Players_dbo.JN_Country_JN_Country_ID\". The
>   conflict occurred in database \"JuventusApk\", table
>   \"dbo.JN_Players\", column 'JN_Country_ID'.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

This is true.Because Registered a player for this country

Second time => item is 14

error :

> InnerException    {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
>   constraint \"FK_dbo.JN_Players_dbo.JN_Country_JN_Country_ID\". The
>   conflict occurred in database \"JuventusApk\", table
>   \"dbo.JN_Players\", column 'JN_Country_ID'.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

This is not true.No players registered for this country. Why this error occurs

Comment: Is your _service.Delete() method reusing the same context?

Comment: The database seems to think it *is* true.  Are you sure that constraint is defined the way you think it's defined?  Are you sure the data is in the state you think it's in?  When do you *commit* your changes from the data context to the database, anyway?  Side note: Empty `catch` blocks are a *famously* bad idea.

Comment: I would look in the foreign key to make sure that it is actually doing what we 'assume' it is doing.  Can you post it as well?